# ICD loader reports not usable format after installing OpenCL

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, opencl, intel

I installed OpenCL on my Ubuntu 14.04 using this link: http://yuleiming.com/install-intel-opencl-on-ubuntu-14-04/ However when I followed last step:

```
sudo clinfo | grep Intel
```

I got the following error:

```
ICD loader reports not usable format
```

What might have gone wrong? I've also installed clinfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the guide you followed and it installs the old OpenCL Driver for Inetl CPUS. I have list down steps for the latest OpenCL Driver:

- install rpm

  > sudo apt-get install -y rpm alien libnuma1
- install clinfo utility

  > sudo apt-get install clinfo
- download and install the OpenCL™ Runtime for Intel® Core™ and Intel® Xeon® Processors

  > wget -c http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/9019/opencl_runtime_16.1.1_x64_ubuntu_6.4.0.25.tgz
  >
  > tar xvzf opencl_runtime_16.1.1_x64_ubuntu_6.4.0.25.tgz
  >
  > cd opencl_runtime_16.1.1_x64_ubuntu_6.4.0.25
  >
  > sudo rpm --import PUBLIC_KEY.PUB
  >
  > cd rpm
  >
  > fakeroot alien --to-deb opencl-1.2-base-6.4.0.25-1.x86_64.rpm
  >
  > fakeroot alien --to-deb opencl-1.2-intel-cpu-6.4.0.25-1.x86_64.rpm
  >
  > sudo dpkg -i opencl-1.2-base_6.4.0.25-2_amd64.deb
  >
  > sudo dpkg -i opencl-1.2-intel-cpu_6.4.0.25-2_amd64.deb

>
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/intelOpenCL.conf

and add the following line -> /opt/intel/intel-opencl-1.2-6.0.0.1049/lib64

- create a symbolic link for Intel ICD

  > sudo ln /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-6.4.0.25/etc/intel64.icd /etc/OpenCL/vendors/intel64.icd
  >
  > sudo ldconfig
- Now you can check Intel OpenCL with *clinfo*

  > sudo clinfo | grep Intel

Now, you can proceed with [OpenCL SDK installation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl/download).

Comment: Can you tell me how I can uninstall the already installed OpenCL before proceeding with the procedure suggested? Should I delete the added lines in Bashrc file?

Comment: Use $sudo apt-get purge opencl*. And also update the bashrc with updated paths after installation of new SDK.